# side-by-side accordion going to left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a accordion which is side-by-side but the problem is when i  open the first accordion on right side ( Section 5)  its going to bottom on the  below (Section 4) but i don,'t want this and also when the page will open in browser it should be below the (section 4). on left .
i have try with different code ....there are different different issue is comming.

here is the link

```
https://codepen.io/soumenework/full/gOGwmaP
```

```js
 // Get all Accordion and Panel
 let accHeading = document.querySelectorAll(".ttb .accordion");
 let accPanel = document.querySelectorAll(".ttb .accordion-panel");
 
 for (let i = 0; i < accHeading.length; i++) {
     // Execute whenever an accordion is clicked 
     accHeading[i].onclick = function() {
         if (this.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight) {
            hidePanels();     // Hide All open Panels 
         } else {
            showPanel(this);  // Show the panel
         } 
     };
 }
 
 // Function to Show a Panel
 function showPanel(elem) {
   hidePanels();
   elem.classList.add("active");
   elem.nextElementSibling.style.maxHeight = elem.nextElementSibling.scrollHeight + "px";
 }
 
 // Function to Hide all shown Panels
 function hidePanels() {
   for (let i = 0; i < accPanel.length; i++) {
       accPanel[i].style.maxHeight = null;
       accHeading[i].classList.remove("active");
   }
 }
```

```css
  * {box-sizing: border-box;}
            
           
  .accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  
  
  .active, .accordion:hover, .accordion:hover::after {
    background-color: #007eff;
    color: white;
  }
  
 
  .ttb .accordion::after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
  }
  

  .ttb .active::after {
    content: "\2212";
    color: white;
  }
  
 
  .accordion-panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  }
  

.dw {
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-column-gap: 0;
column-gap:10px;

-moz-column-count: 2;
column-count: 2;
}

.dw-pnl {
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
break-inside: avoid;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.dw {
-moz-column-count: 1;
column-count: 1;
}
}
```

```html
 <div class="dw">
   
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb ">
        <h2 class="accordion active">Section  1</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel" style="max-height: 68px;">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div> 
      
    </div>
 
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section 2</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div> 
      
    </div>
   
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section 3</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section 4</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section 5</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section 6</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
  
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section 7</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
  
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb no_opcity">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section 8</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb no_opcity">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section  9</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
    <div class="dw-pnl dw-pnl--fcs ttb no_opcity">
        <h2 class="accordion ">Section  10</h2>
        <div  class="accordion-panel">
          <p>aaa Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
        </div>       
    </div>
 
  
   
   
    
   
    </div>
```

please help
thank you

Comment: Could you please clear that what you want exactly in your question so I can help you? I don't understand why did you implement one accordion in two column like this? maybe we can implement your requirements in another way

Comment: no ....this is the dseign in psd. and i don't want to use two accordion and it can be use in loop for wp post type

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem with section 5 starting at the right side is because of > break-inside: avoid; < in your css code at line 54

Try changing that to auto or something else!

It also seemed that when opening section 5 it first opens on the right side.. i do not (yet) have an answer for that!

Comment: i have tried that but not effecting . with this ---- break-inside: avoid;

Comment: For me that seems to solve it > https://imgur.com/a/QpXS1Qf

Comment: could i see that without login imgur.com ?

Comment: My bad! https://i.imgur.com/TNMyb3i.png

Comment: so could you share the code here?

Comment: It's exactly the same code from the codepen you provided! I just changed avoid to auto on line 54 of the CSS file.

Comment: no...... now it's staying only the accordion content but the header still going to bellow

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you wanna accomplish?